# Problem regarding import products

Tags: product, import, export

When I do an export of my products and open this .csv list in excel and add the new products, i always recieve a error regarding the SKU 
See image below. 
[image]

Comment: i think its better to use magmi, it will do magic for uploading products. even i thought its difficult. but you can learn within a day.

Comment: It would help if you showed how you added the new products

Comment: @fschmengler Thanks for your suggestions, i will surely do that.

Comment: @wesley please go through this [page](http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) , this is official magmi wiki page and if you find any doubts , feel free to ask.....

Comment: I meant Wesley ;)

Answer (score 1):

I was importing the products through csv.Sometime i used to get Skip import row, required field “sku” not defined error.I checked sku coloum wheather it is empty.No not everything is filled.so after some google i got solution.

In most cases your .CSV file needs to be saved in UTF-8 format:

1. First, ensure all your fields are properly filled in Excel or Open Office Calc.
2. Create and edit a copy of your .CSV file.
3. Save the file as Comma Separated Values (.CSV) if you haven’t already done so.
4. Open the file with a text editor such as NOTEPAD or TEXTEDIT.
5. Go to File > Save As .Your filename should end with “.csv.” Example: import.csv
6. Under Save as type select All files (*.*)
7. Under Encoding (Plain Text Encoding in TEXTEDIT) select UTF-8
8. Save the file ready for reimporting into Magento
9. Run the import again now all products will be imported without any error.